# How to archive cell changes in new tab?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google sheet that I'm collecting some statistics in.  There is a particular cell that I'd like to track changes in a separate tab. I'm looking for a function to copy cell if the cell data changes to a new cell in a different tab.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. By the way that can't be done by using a spreadsheet function but Google Apps Script on edit trigger could be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but a new feature was added to Google Sheets that tracks down all changes of any given cell:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

**Note:** Some changes might not show up in the edit history. Some examples are:

- Added or deleted rows and columns
- Changes to the cell's format
- Changes made by formulas

Answer (score 0):

- you will need something like this:

  ```
  function onEdit() {
      var reference = 'Sheet1!A2'; 
      var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(reference);
      rng.setValue(rng.getValue()+1);
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
      var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A2");
      var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var values = source.getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f) {return f})});
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  ```
- anytime cell `Sheet1!A2` changes the range `Sheet1!A2` gets archived in `Sheet2`